# How can we run sudo rpm commands using ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-2.x, rhel7, ansible-inventory

In my ansible role, I have a task where I am trying to install Jenkins rpm. The rpm is located in /tmp directory on target host. Also, I have permission to run the command, "sudo /bin/rpm -Uvh /tmp/jenkins-2.107.1.2-1.1.noarch.rpm" which work when I tried to run it on the server directly. But running the same command via command module it fails.

Task :

```
- name: run the rpm command on masters
  command: sudo /bin/rpm -Uvh jenkins-2.107.1.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
  args:
    chdir: /tmp
```

Error:

```
fatal: [xxxx. xxx.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "'sudo rpm' -Uvh 'jenkins-2.107.1.2-1.1.noarch.rpm'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Permission on target host :

```
User XXXX may run the following commands on target_Host_Name:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service jenkins stop, /usr/sbin/service jenkins start, /bin/rpm -Uvh jenkins*.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ansible` `yum` module with `become: true` rather than the `command` module with `sudo` for example:

```
- name: install jenkins rpm from a local file
  yum:
    name: /tmp/jenkins-2.107.1.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
    state: present
  become: true
```

**Note**: the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` is explicit, the file `/tmp/jenkins-2.107.1.2-1.1.noarch.rpm` does not exist. You need to ensure that the file exists before attempting to install the `rpm`.

For additional information on privilege escalation in `ansible` refer to: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html